# Hebrew Text has a lot of boxes. Is it only me?

Tags: support, bug, hebrew

From this question: [How should we understand the Torah’s comparison of a tree to a “man”? What message is the Torah trying to convey?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/76207/how-should-we-understand-the-torah-s-comparison-of-a-tree-to-a-man-what-messa)

[image: Lots of boxes]

Is this a system-wide issue, or just one that I have? There are a lot of boxes in the hebrew. I think it might be because the pasted text may have ta'amim, that are not being displayed properly.

If this is not a system-wide problem, any tips on how to solve it?

I'm using Chromium on Linux. Lubuntu 16.04. I do not have any special Hebrew support enabled. To make matters more interesting, I'm answering this on my phone (chrome on iOS 9.3.2), and the text that I pasted in the question does show up properly with the ta'amim. No boxes.

Comments also report a problem with Chrome on Ubuntu but that it works with Chrome on Windows and Mac.

---

A further proof that this may be the ta'amim. Here is a copy paste from [here](http://www.chabad.org/parshah/torahreading_cdo/aid/2495812/jewish/Ki-Teitzei-Torah-Reading.htm) (where the ta'amim are included).

כִּֽי־תֵצֵ֥א לַמִּלְחָמָ֖ה עַל־אֹֽיְבֶ֑יךָ וּנְתָנ֞וֹ יְהֹוָ֧ה אֱלֹהֶ֛יךָ בְּיָדֶ֖ךָ וְשָׁבִ֥יתָ שִׁבְיֽוֹ:

This shows a bunch of boxes for me, where the letters that have the Ta'amim should be. Does it show up properly for anyone else?

---

Here's another one: [What does the munach say?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/36788/what-does-the-munach-say)

And another one: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/84258/603

Comment: Is it all questions with Hebrew or just that one?  If just that one, can you edit in a link to it?  (I tried searching for the title in your screen shot and didn't find it.)  Thanks.

Comment: It definitely happens on more than one, but not all of them. This one, for example, is fine: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/25774/is-the-tree-of-the-field-a-man

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I'm seeing Hebrew with *ta'amim* both there and in your post here, but I've definitely seen boxes somewhere in the past (phone, maybe?).  What browser are you using?

Comment: "the ideal requirement for Hebrew is to be able to display all the cantillation marks also, which most fonts don't do very well. The open-source Taamey Frank CLM font [here](http://culmus.sourceforge.net/taamim/) is probably the best for cantillation marks" ([source](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Grease_pit/2013/November#Language-specific_CSS_at_MediaWiki:Common.css))

Comment: @monica. I'm using chromium on Linux. Lubuntu 16.04.  I do not have any special Hebrew support enabled. To make matters more interesting, I'm answering this on my phone (chrome on iOS 9.3.2), and the text that I pasted in the question does show up properly with the ta'amim. No boxes

Comment: Chrome on Ubuntu; same problem.

Comment: @Menachem is this still happening to you?  If you see it on other questions, please edit in links.  The more data we can give SE, the better the chances that they'll be able to figure out the cause.  Thanks.

Comment: @MonicaCellio: Still happening. As I come across links I'll add them here

Comment: [meta-tag:status-norepro] Chrome on Windows

Comment: The Community "user" bumped the question again. [(Source.)](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/4147/revisions) Is this still happening to you? P.S. You may want to cross-post to Ask Ubuntu and to edit each question to include a link to the other.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's your OS? Are you on a computer or a phone/tablet?

Comment: on a computer running lubuntu (an ubuntu derivative)

Answer (score 0):

It looks fine to me, but it might be because my computer is able to go to and fro between typing English and Hebrew. As @DonielF put it, it might also be the device you're on.